# SQLite using ContentValues with BigInteger data type?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, biginteger

So, I am trying to store some data on the `SQLite` db in Android,

The table structure is something like this:

```
e BIGINT NOT NULL, n BIGINT NOT NULL, phoneNo TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

and I'm trying to do it using something like this:

```
BigInteger e, n;
String phoneNo;
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(KEY_PUB_E, e);
initialValues.put(KEY_PUB_N, n);
initialValues.put(KEY_PUB_PHONE, phoneNo);
mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
```

But the ContentValues wont accept BigInteger data type, so im thinking of using int or long, but would it cause the data to change? and SQLite does support BIGINT right?

There is another option for me which is using execSQL method, but later there is a part where i need to involve a lot of coloumns and would make it too complicated...

How should I do this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Thank for the help, woodshy,

the simplest solution im going for is to store the value as text, and converting it back to BigInteger when i retrieve it. shouldnt be a problem as this isnt done too often during the application's runtime...

what do you think about this?

Answer (score 2):

quote from [HERE](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) : INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

You could use long datatype, or you could use [longValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue%28%29) method of Bigint.

Comment: thank you, and yes, i read that documentation before, i assume it stores based on the value of the data itself, but what im not sure is whether converting an BigInteger value to a long data type would cause any problem? im afraid using longValue() would cause the value to be incorrect..

Comment: what problems are you afraid of?

Comment: such as the value is too big to fit in a long, or the value of the data would be changed...

Comment: What data are you going to store in that field? Will you accept such big values as a correct input?

Comment: im going to store an public encryption key received from other people. it will be generated randomly